# Netbeans Tomcat Server Issue

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, server

I am currently trying to hook Tomcat up to Netbeans and run a web project on it.  I have set up a server with a username and password, but keep getting this error message.  I have also added the server log below for more details. :

```
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
In-place deployment at C:\Ryan Drive\Web Development\Java\NetBeans\Projects\WebApplication5\build\web
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Frmhaa%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext8651336917198990861.xml&path=/WebApplication5
FAIL - Failed to deploy application at context path /WebApplication5
C:\Ryan Drive\Web Development\Java\NetBeans\Projects\WebApplication5\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Here is the server log below.  It looks like access is denied possibly?  But I have no idea why this is happening.  I get the same server log error every time I run the server, independent of project.

```
13-Jun-2016 18:14:22.419 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
13-Jun-2016 18:14:22.422 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 124 ms
13-Jun-2016 18:14:22.424 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
13-Jun-2016 18:14:22.431 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
13-Jun-2016 18:14:22.432 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 773 ms
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\ch07_ex2_download.xml (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.copyInternal(ManagerServlet.java:1626)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.copy(ManagerServlet.java:1589)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:880)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: "See the server log for details." What are the details in the server log?

Comment: @JoachimRohde, I added the server log above.  Thanks.

Comment: What part of `Access is denied` don't you understand?

Comment: @EJP Why access would be denied?

Comment: I guess you need admin privileges to access C:\Program Files. Try to move your Tomcat installation into your user directory and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same failed to deploy and access denied messages.

Close netbeans and run it as Adminstrator. It grants all necessary permissions to run tomcat.

If it doesn't work, it might be some configuration, check the videos below. They helped me a lot
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKMgr8uNvGM and 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psvuLBVeTzQ

Comment: Referring to a video as an answer is not very useful, instead try to resume what the solution is when you had said -  If it doesn't work - , this way if the link disappear your solution still good enough.

Comment: Hi Djemai,
I understand what you mean, but I'm not writting down how to install and configure a server (too extense and not the point). And if I had put a link with the documentation on how to do it, it would have the same result as the video link.

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down the tomcat server, and then try to clean-build the project again.

Liron

Comment: 1. Try stopping tomcat.
2. Remove the following file (or change its extension): C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\ch07_ex2_download.xml
3. Try to clean and build
4. Start the tomcat server again.